# Colon separated list in Python how to replace selected elements

Tags: python

With the help of an answer to [Replacing selected elements in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350400/replacing-selected-elements-in-a-list-in-python), I have the following test code working :

```
newline = [10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40]
def replace_element(newline, new_element, indices):
    for i in indices:
        newline[6] = (newline[6] - 30) * 1.13
    return newline

newline = replace_element(newline, newline[6] , [6])
print(newline)
```

However my data stream to rrdtool requires colon separators instead of commas (i.e. 24.73:0.06:264.44:0.61:886.55:2.14:88.91:0.21 ) so I get a

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Can I handle this in code or do I need to replace the commas after the replace_element line?

Answer (score 2):

Strings aren't really mutable (I think), but they have a `split` method that turn them into lists:

```
>>> data = '24.73:0.06:264.44:0.61:886.55:2.14:88.91:0.21'
>>> data.split(':')
['24.73', '0.06', '264.44', '0.61', '886.55', '2.14', '88.91', '0.21']
```

So that's a list of strings. Maybe you want them to be actual numbers:

```
>>> data_as_list = list(map(float, data.split(':')))
>>> data_as_list
[24.73, 0.06, 264.44, 0.61, 886.55, 2.14, 88.91, 0.21]
```

Even if you don't do that, you can still assign anything you want:

```
>>> data_as_list[6] = 'some other thing'
>>> data_as_list
[24.73, 0.06, 264.44, 0.61, 886.55, 2.14, 'some other thing', 0.21]
```

And then you can turn it back into a string:

```
>>> ':'.join(map(str, data_as_list))
'24.73:0.06:264.44:0.61:886.55:2.14:some other thing:0.21'
```

Comment: thanks to both respondents. Both helped with my understanding of the core issue.